# Grab URLs for dynamic CubeCart menu

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, megamenu, ioncube

I've been trying to figure out a way to implement a mega menu into CubeCart and I'm stuck after constructing the menu on how best to hook it up to the CubeCarts category system. From what I can tell (or-though I could be wrong) I can't get to the php I need to edit to customize the category system because it's encrypted with ioncube.

Basically I want to structure my menu as such using CubeCarts categories to construct a megamenu https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwnpX.png . It's also live [here](http://101share.co.uk/)

I can't seem to get my head round the best way to do this with CubeCarts weird structure, would be great if someone could tell me the best way to approach this as there is next to no documentation out there for it. Would it be possible for me to grab the URLs via JS? I would hard code it except I'll need to have it update as the categories are changed in the admin area.

I really hope this isn't too general of a question because I'm really stuck on this and any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Cubecart should probably be assisting you with this, perhaps as part of a support contract if that applies in your case. If CC have encoded more than you feel that they should have, also contact them to let them know. I'm associated with ionCube, but do not advocate encoding everything. While it can be in the best interest of both provider and customer to encode some parts of an application, it is important for a provider to consider which parts should be left open, and to re-evaluate where the boundary is from time to time based on feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick. Unfortunately I've tried endlessly to reason with the guys at CubeCart, but they are just unreasonable, even after purchasing their "Support Credits" just to gain the privilege of talking to them, they still refused to help me or give any full answers to my questions, which is why I thought I should at least try asking here.